# running scala code on vscode and raises an error : No build target could be found for the path

Tags: scala

I am trying to run a scala project on vscode for the first time. I installed Java, and scala installer for windows. I imported the build tools of the sbt's version mentionned in the code and when I try to run the build.sbt code, it raises the following error: No build target could be found for the path.

Can somebody help me please ?

Thank You.

I tried to correct the path name but It did not work.

Comment: Are you able to run the code using **sbt** without **vscode**? Also, can you share your setup?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When I run the command "sbt clean compile" , I get an  error "Couldn't run bloopGenerate. The issue could be caused by failing to compile the project.".  
I am trying to run the code using vscode on Windows.

Comment: So it seems **bloop** is having issues, you may try to search for its logs. Or tell **vscode** to use **sbt** as the BSP instead of **bloop**.